# Is there a different authorization logic when accessing backend via mobile (specifically iphone) browser versus desktop (chrome) browser?

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, axios

When I try to access a certain page, my backend determines whether the logged in user is allowed to see the page or not. The backend I am using is django/django-rest, and for frontend I am using react (axios for http calls).

This is an example of my api call. I want to get the inventory for a user.

```
        axios.get(this.url, this.config)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    products: res.data
                })
                if (res.data.length > 0) {
                    if (!res.data[0].is_owner) {
                        this.setState({
                            inventory_owner: res.data[0].user_name,
                            is_owner: res.data[0].is_owner
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(res => {
                console.log("config2 what happened",this.config)
            })
```

this.url is the api url, and this.config is:

```
    config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    }
```

I know localStorage is a bad practice but I just wanted to get it working first. The issue I am encountering is that when I make this call on my browser, everything works fine. When I try on my iphone and use chrome browser, I get this in the log: `Unauthorized: /api/inventory/f11e72d5-ae28-406f-8cca-a4260a9e65a8/`. I believe this message is auto generated by django-rest or django-rest-auth, so that means it doesn't even begin my ViewSet logic yet (there are slightly more rules for whether a person is allowed to see an inventory, but that code doesn't even get executed yet). 
What could be causing this different behavior? It most likely has to do with the token, but I can indeed verify the token is present in the localStorage, as I can log in with no problems on either browser.

Comment: I don't see the step when you add `token` to localStorage. When do you do that?

Comment: Ah sorry didnt show that part. That's done in some other part of the code. I just set item in localstorage for that.